# Regex splitting a string to an array using java and Tika

Tags: java, regex, apache-tika

Im trying to take the Tika output (pdf to text) and split the result into an array of words - or groups of characters.

im using something like....

```
String str = contenthandler.toString();
  String[] splitArray = str.split("\\s+");

  for (String word : splitArray){
    System.out.println(word);
  }
```

but im not getting splits where i expect them - between the words.  I'd like to preserve line breaks, pages, tabs, etc... and just nix the white space. Sample text from Tika looks like:

```
"...or supplemented except by a written instrument signed by both parties.  The unenforceability of any provision on this Agreement shall not affect the enforceability of any other provision of this Agreement.  Neither this Agreement nor the disclosure of any Confidential Information pursuant to this Agreement by any party shall restrict such party from disclosing any of its Confidential Information to any third party...."
```

I was playing around with regex on http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/

patterns like [^a-zA-Z] find the spaces, while /s+ does not.  How do I split on these guys?

Comment: Fyi, tabs and line breaks ARE whitespace. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html for more info on java regex. Also, `\s` is defined as: `A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`

Comment: Can you tell us what you're getting instead? And what you're expecting? The code seems fine to me at first glance (although tabs and newlines will also be included as delimiters with `\s`)

Comment: Thanks. So given that explanation - why doesn't \s+ find the spaces between the words?

Comment: I want each word as an array element.  I am getting splits on line returns, new lines and page breaks.  Just not between the words. again [^a-zA-Z] splits the words, so something is there - just not an /s.

Comment: \W gets it, but also splits charactors like , !@#$ etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabs and line breaks are whitespace.  If you simply want to split on one or more space characters, you need to do

```
String[] splitArray = str.split(" +");
```

***EDIT***

In response to OP comments - it would appear that the spaces are not being matched by `\s+`.  In which case, the characters (spaces) between words are none of [`[" ",\t, \n, \x0B, \f, \r\]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)*.  You could try matching `\b` (this is a word boundary).  To really find out what the characters are - paste the string into a good text editor and view the raw characters (e.g. in Notepad++ it would be view -> show all characters).  Note the hex code of the characters between words and check what that is.

***EDIT following OP test***

By examining the hex representation of the text (via [edithex.com](http://www.edithex.com)), OP determined that the space character was a non-breaking space (0xA0).  Thus, this code satisfies the requirement:

```
String[] splitArray = str.split("\xA0")
```

It seems that PDFs commonly encode spaces as characters other than the standard space (0xA0). This [blogpost](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2011/09/understanding-the-pdf-file-format-%E2%80%93-space-is-a-special-character/) implies that PDFs might not encode spaces as standard spaces (ASCII code 0x20 = 32). The various options for space characters that \s will not pick up [are here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).

---

*In the example text, they *are* spaces, but that must have been changed in the copy / paste

Comment: I see what you're saying, i wont get the exact results im looking for (i will not be preserving line breaks and tabs) - not the end of the world, i can work around that.  BUT, " +" is not picking up the spaces either.

Comment: You could try pasting the exact output from Tika into here http://www.edithex.com/ and see what the hex code of the characters between words are?  20 is a space, 0A a newline, 09 a tab

Comment: I've been intrigued by this.  This link https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2011/09/understanding-the-pdf-file-format-%E2%80%93-space-is-a-special-character/ implies that PDFs might not encode spaces as standard spaces (ASCII code 0x20 = 32).  This one implies there might be a few different options of how the PDF encodes a space http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/SpecialChars.html.  If the pdf is public  - can you post it somewhere so we can look at it?

Comment: WOW!!! Thanks J.  Very nice tool (edithex).  Im able to determine the character is a "non-break" space (A0).  So the regex \xA0 resolves it.